# How to display only 2 week in CalendarView in android?

Tags: android, calendar, calendarview

How to display only 2 week in CalendarView?

Is there a way to display a calendarview for 2 weeks at a time instead of the full month(4 weeks)? Please see the attached images.

I would still like to retain the gestures

Scrolling left/right will change months
Scrolling up/down will show me the following weeks.
Hoping that someone can point me in the right direction.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Calendar View, show only 2 weeks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38953036/android-calendar-view-show-only-2-weeks)

Comment: Good question why people down votes they dont even idea

Answer (score 2):

[Materialdesignweekview](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview)
try this